# Where to buy english windows 7 home premium

Tags: windows-7, windows

I live in russia and I'd like to buy english version of windows 7 home premium (download edition). However, it looks like english version of microsoft store only sells box edition that should be shipped via mail. I'm also kinda confused about regional restrictions (i.e. is it "safe" to buy windows from another region?)

So, where can I buy it?

Answer (score 2):

The key works for all languages.

Download the English ISO from here: http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-58997.iso (64Bit) or here: http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-58996.iso (32Bit), use your Key and reinstall Windows 7 Home Premium.

Comment: I don't have windows 7 key and I'm not eligible for upgrade. I've asked the question because I'm wasn't exactly sure where to buy the key.

Comment: buy a Russian license and download the English ISOs